# mixed-models with two random effects - statsmodels

Tags: python, r, statsmodels, mixed-models

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

df = pd.read_csv('http://www.bodowinter.com/tutorial/politeness_data.csv')
df = df.drop(38)
```

In `R` I would do:

```
lmer(frequency ~ attitude + (1|subject) + (1|scenario), data=df)
```

which in `R` gives me:

```
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 scenario (Intercept)  219     14.80   
 subject  (Intercept) 4015     63.36   
 Residual              646     25.42   
Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)  202.588     26.754   7.572
attitudepol  -19.695      5.585  -3.527
```

I tried to do the same with `statsmodels`:

```
model = smf.mixedlm("frequency ~ attitude", data=df, groups=df[["subject","scenario"]]).fit()
```

But `model.summary()` gives me a different output:

```
      Mixed Linear Model Regression Results
=======================================================
Model:            MixedLM Dependent Variable: frequency
No. Observations: 83      Method:             REML     
No. Groups:       2       Scale:              0.0000   
Min. group size:  1       Likelihood:         inf      
Max. group size:  1       Converged:          Yes      
Mean group size:  1.0                                  
-------------------------------------------------------
                  Coef.  Std.Err. z P>|z| [0.025 0.975]
-------------------------------------------------------
Intercept        204.500                               
attitude[T.pol]    8.800                               
groups RE          0.000                               
=======================================================
```

Comment: Did you take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39152729/how-to-have-multiple-groups-in-python-statsmodels-linear-mixed-effects-model)?

Comment: @erocoar: Thanks for the link. Yes, I had already seen that post but at that time (2 years ago) this didn't seem possible, as suggested in Ben Bolker's answer. I was wondering if things have changed since then.

Comment: statsmodels MixedLM uses a variance component option separately from the groups to allow for crossed effects.

Comment: @user333700: Thanks for your comment. I'm really a beginner in statsmodel and MixedLM, could you help me set up the model so that I can see how to get equivalent results to the lmer package? Maybe you could post an answer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The code below reproduces the R results.  Since this is a crossed model with no independent groups, you need to put everyone in the same group and specify the random effects using variance components.

```
import pandas as pd                                                                                                        
import statsmodels.api as sm                                                                                               
                                                                                                                           
df = pd.read_csv('http://www.bodowinter.com/uploads/1/2/9/3/129362560/politeness_data.csv')                                                 
df = df.dropna()                                                                                                           
df["group"] = 1                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                           
vcf = {"scenario": "0 + C(scenario)", "subject": "0 + C(subject)"}                                                         
model = sm.MixedLM.from_formula("frequency ~ attitude", groups="group",                                                    
                                vc_formula=vcf, re_formula="0", data=df)                                                   
result = model.fit()
```

Here are the results:

```
            Mixed Linear Model Regression Results
==============================================================
Model:               MixedLM   Dependent Variable:   frequency
No. Observations:    83        Method:               REML     
No. Groups:          1         Scale:                646.0163 
Min. group size:     83        Likelihood:           -396.7268
Max. group size:     83        Converged:            Yes      
Mean group size:     83.0                                     
--------------------------------------------------------------
                 Coef.   Std.Err.   z    P>|z|  [0.025  0.975]
--------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept        202.588   26.754  7.572 0.000 150.152 255.025
attitude[T.pol]  -19.695    5.585 -3.526 0.000 -30.641  -8.748
scenario Var     218.991    6.476                             
subject Var     4014.616  104.614                             
==============================================================
```

Answer (score 3):

The only way I could think of to semi-reproduce this is to simply concatenate your groups.

```
df["grp"] = df["subject"].astype(str) + df["scenario"].astype(str)
model = smf.mixedlm("frequency ~ attitude", data=df, groups=df["grp"]).fit()

model.summary()
Out[87]: 
<class 'statsmodels.iolib.summary2.Summary'>
"""
            Mixed Linear Model Regression Results
==============================================================
Model:               MixedLM   Dependent Variable:   frequency
No. Observations:    83        Method:               REML     
No. Groups:          42        Scale:                615.6961 
Min. group size:     1         Likelihood:           -430.8261
Max. group size:     2         Converged:            Yes      
Mean group size:     2.0                                      
--------------------------------------------------------------
                 Coef.   Std.Err.   z    P>|z|  [0.025  0.975]
--------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept        202.588   10.078 20.102 0.000 182.836 222.340
attitude[T.pol]  -19.618    5.476 -3.582 0.000 -30.350  -8.885
groups RE       3650.021   50.224                             
==============================================================

"""
```

Answer (score 2):

The `lmer` equivalent of your `smf.mixedlm` model would be something like this:

```
lmer(frequency ~ attitude + (1 + attitude|subject) + (1 + attitude|scenario), data = df)
```

Explanation of the terms:

1. A global intercept (you can disable the global intercept with `frequency ~ 0 + attitude + ...`)
2. An global slope for the fixed effect `attitude`.
3. A random intercept vor `subject` (i.e. for each level of `subject` you get a deviation from the global intercept), and the deviation from the fixed effect slope for `attitude` within each level of `subject`, allowing for correlation between random intercept and slope.
4. The equivalent random intercept and slope terms for `scenario`.

Note, if you want to allow random intercept and slope to vary freely (i.e. enforcing a zero correlation between intercept and slope) you'd have to replace `(1 + attitude|subject)` with `(1|subject) + (0 + attitude|subject)`, and similarly for `scenario`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However I'm trying to find the smf.mixedlm equivalent of the lmer model shown in the question, not the other way round.

Comment: @HappyPy Ah in that case, I completely misunderstood. Sorry, I'm not very familiar with `smf.mixedlm`, so won't be able to help.